# Check if {{ path() }} is current {{ path() }} in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How do I check if the current page is this path:

```
{{ path('someNamePath') }}
```

I want to set a css class to the `<a>` element or possible remove it altogether, e.g.

```
{% if  isCurrentPath('someNamePath') %}
    <a href="{{ path('someNamePath') }}" class="YouAreHere">My Link</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ path('someNamePath') }}">My Link</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`app.request.get('_route')` is probably what you are looking for:

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') == 'current_route' %}
    <a href="{{ path('current_route') }}" class="YouAreHere">My Link</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ path('some_other_route') }}">My Link</a>
{% endif %}
```

In case you want to use uri instead, you can use `app.request.uri`.

Comment: if I use a {% render 'AppBundle:Sidebar:render' %} to render the sidebar then app.request.get('_route') return '_internal' value always. How can I get a _route of the current page?

Comment: You can't and it's by design (for now) for subrequests.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use the "controller_name" variable. This is added in every controller generated by the symfony CLI. Of yourse you can, and probably should, add it there yourself if its not present.

Then you can do a check like this: `{% if controller_name == "DashboardController" %}active{% endif %}`